# Tensorflow-gpu: CUDA_ERROR_OUT_OF_MEMORY

Tags: python, gpu, cuda

I am relatively new to tensorflow and tried to install tensorflow-gpu on a Thinkpad P1 (Nvidia Quadro P2000) running with Pop!_OS 18.10. I installed tensorflow-gpu into a new conda environment and used the conda install command.

Now, after running simple python scripts as shown below a 2-3 times, I always encounter a CUDA_ERROR_OUT_OF_MEMORY error. Does anyone know what the problem might be here? I have to mention, that I had quite some troubles to install tensorflow-gpu on my laptop before. I first tried it on ubuntu, which didn't work out.

The code and the warnings are attached below.

code:

```
import tensorflow as tf

a = tf.constant(1)
b = tf.constant(2)
sum_tensor = a + b

with tf.Session() as session:
 answer = session.run(sum_tensor)
 print('a + b = %d' % answer)
```

errors:

```
runfile('/home/andrschl/PycharmProjects/Test/Test.py', wdir='/home/andrschl/PycharmProjects/Test')
2019-05-03 11:30:59.587115: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:141] Your CPU supports instructions that this TensorFlow binary was not compiled to use: SSE4.1 SSE4.2 AVX AVX2 FMA
2019-05-03 11:30:59.610905: I tensorflow/core/platform/profile_utils/cpu_utils.cc:94] CPU Frequency: 2712000000 Hz
2019-05-03 11:30:59.611871: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/service.cc:150] XLA service 0x5625de849590 executing computations on platform Host. Devices:
2019-05-03 11:30:59.611905: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/service.cc:158]   StreamExecutor device (0): <undefined>, <undefined>
2019-05-03 11:30:59.633882: W tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/platform_util.cc:240] unable to create StreamExecutor for CUDA:0: failed initializing StreamExecutor for CUDA device ordinal 0: Internal: failed call to cuDevicePrimaryCtxRetain: CUDA_ERROR_OUT_OF_MEMORY: out of memory; total memory reported: 4236312576
2019-05-03 11:30:59.633965: F tensorflow/stream_executor/lib/statusor.cc:34] Attempting to fetch value instead of handling error Internal: no supported devices found for platform CUDA
Process finished with exit code 134 (interrupted by signal 6: SIGABRT)
```

Thanks in advance for your answers!

Answer (score 0):

Have you attempted to configure the gpu memory growth:

```
import tensorflow as tf
config = tf.ConfigProto()
config.gpu_options.allow_growth=True
sess = tf.Session(config=config)
```

or alternatively:

```
# Creates a graph.
with tf.device('/device:GPU:2'):
  a = tf.constant([1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0], shape=[2, 3], name='a')
  b = tf.constant([1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0], shape=[3, 2], name='b')
  c = tf.matmul(a, b)
# Creates a session with allow_soft_placement and log_device_placement set
# to True.
sess = tf.Session(config=tf.ConfigProto(
      allow_soft_placement=True, log_device_placement=True))
# Runs the op.
print(sess.run(c))
```

There are more options and information from Tensorflow [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/using_gpu#allowing_gpu_memory_growth)

I have also seen some more brutish approaches like:

```
del model
gc.collect()
```

or inside of Keras

```
def clear_cuda_memory():
    from keras import backend as K

    for i in range(5):K.clear_session()
    return True
cuda = clear_cuda_memory()
```

The above is run multiple times to account for processes that are slow to release memory.

Another full brute force approach is to kill the python process & or the ipython kernel.

I haven't found the perfect solution yet.  Tensorflow 2.0 might address some issues; my current version is 1.14.0.